# Increased current at the output of a switch

Tags: current, switches

I am forcing a current at the output of a switch up to 25mA.

The switch can handle only a limited current depending on its size.

Question: Where will the rest of the current come from? What does the negative voltage at the output of the switch mean in practice?

The switch is a transmission gate.

[image: testbench]

[image: negative voltage]

Answer (score 0):

Most devices, transmission gate included, have protection diodes I/O to power rails.

These diodes are usually included in SPICE models, to capture just this sort of behaviour.

The 1v you are seeing is the voltage drop across the output-to-ground diode. The limited input current is the limited differential voltage across the resistance of the channel.